# my onload function sequence is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, couchdb

What I'm trying to do is getting data from a database and when the page loads they will show on the screen. when a user is logged in it has an database url that is saved in a variable `db` and I use `db.allDocs` to get all data from that user.

Now. I've got it working on a button `<button onclick="showInfoItems()">`
But when I try it onload, it does work, but not with the correct database. This is because the user is unknown for some reason.

my code:

```
<body>
<ul id="info-lijst"></ul>
<script src="js/showinfo.js"></script>
<script>onload = showInfoItems();</script>
```

the user info is known in the showinfo.js, but for some reason the user is undefined, until I press the onclick button.

I thought that, when I first load in the js file (as I do) and then do the onload, it will work, but no. the username is undefined.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix this?

EDIT:

showInfoItems.js:

```
function showInfoItems() {
    console.log(dbrp);
    dbrp.allDocs({
        include_docs: true,
        attachments: true,
        descending: true
    }).then(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        buildInfoItem(doc.rows);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

What the dbrp variable is:
localhost:5984/userdb-undefined
and when i do the onclick it's:
localhost:5984/userdb-1234567890 (username is known)

Comment: so the onload knows the function, but data in that function (the username in the database url not)

Comment: Are you definite the cause is the front-end stuff? You say that it works with on load, but the sequence is wrong.

Comment: can you show your code of `showInfoItems()` please

Comment: document.onload still gives me the items from user-undefined, not the user thats logged in.

Comment: Where do you get your user data from?

Comment: The database is an CouchDB database. I use their getSession to get the username, next I translate that name into hex and add that behind the database url for example localhost:5895/db-'usernameInHex'. which works when i do onlick but not onload.

Comment: You need to define document.onload like this :
`document.onload = function() { showInfoItems(); };` since onload expects a callable. When you set it to `showInfoItems();` only it is executed immediately

Comment: For what I think/see is that when the onload function goes, the js files aren't fully loaded so the username is unknown. But I dont see why they arent fully loaded, cause I load them before the onload function

Comment: `document.onload` is *possibly* supported in Chrome ... and **no other browser**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined onload wrong. It expects a callable function. What you do is calling your function immediately.

```
window.onload = function() {
    showInfoItems()
});
```

**EDIT**

Since this seems to be more an PouchDB issue a expand my answer.

The problem is, that you need to wait for an asynchronous function call. This function is not done when your document is ready. So either you add a callback to this function to trigger another function when it is done or you add dispatch a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('databaseReady'));
```

Then you can listen for this event and bind multiple function to it.

```
document.addEventListener('databaseReady', function() {
    showInfoItems()
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgeyzV?editors=1010

Comment: theoriginal code is actually using `window.onload` incorrectly ... having just onload in the global scope is equivalent to window.onload

Comment: I stated exactly that in 2)

Comment: I've done this now, but still gives me the list of user undefined.

Comment: No, you said "you defined document.onload wrong" ... whereas the code is defining "window.onload wrong" ... having `onload = fn()` is like having `window.onload = fn()` not `document.onload = fn()`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I added document.onload in the comments before at found out I was wrong. I thought the original code already used document.onload. Thanks for the hint, I corrected my answer

Comment: tried both window.onload and document.onload both no success :(

Comment: I created a codepen, does your code look like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKLopJ?editors=1111

Comment: What I missed in your answer before: **I use their getSession to get the username** CouchDB is runnng on the server, so you must fetch the username via AJAX which is asynchronous. You need to wait for it to finish. Can you show your code for getting the username?

Comment: Not using AJAX but the sync function in PouchDB. See the codepen above for the more complete code.

Comment: But PouchDB needs AJAX to sync your data. You need to wati for `db.getSession()` which seems to be anyschronous. You can either set your function call directly into your function or you dispatch a customEvent which your listening to. I updated your codepen with the second option: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgeyzV?editors=1010

Comment: tried your customEvent method, but still, onload it gives me nothing. How do I set my function directly into my function? don't understand that method

Comment: See my codepen. You don't wait for `window.load`. You now listen for your CustomEvent which I called 'databaseReady'. You need to bind an EventListener to it, as I did in the HTML Section of the Codepen and my answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134069/discussion-between-thomagron-and-dennis-koch).

Comment: Hi, it works! the example codepen 'document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('databaseReady'));' i changed that to window.dispatchEvent. aswell as in the html. now it works! thanks for all the help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you use `document.addEventListener` or `window.addEventListener` before? It should work on document too, but you also need to dispatch on document. But since it works everything is good ;)

Comment: used document first. that did not work. after a while I tried again but with window and that did the trick. isn't document something from Jquery?

Comment: Nom it isn't. It also works with document but you need to use the same for `dispatchEvent` and `addEventListener`